Is there a reason why a transform property in a div gets disabled when an animation property with an onclick event is added to it?
I'm still slightly new when it comes to JS/CSS, however I'm having an issue I can't figure out the reason why after searching everywhere. I have a div with a transform scale property on hover, and it also has an onclick animation-play-state to start it, hide a div and display another once the animation ends. When the onclick event was added the transform scale is no longer working.
The divs:
<body>
    <div id="start">
    <div id="button">PUSH</div>
    </div>

    <div id="div-2">
    <!--This div will be hidden with css-->
    </div>
</body>

CSS for the button div with the animations
#button{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color:"red";
    transition: transform .2s;
    animation: roll-out 3s linear ;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

#button:hover{
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

JS onclick event
var btn = document.getElementById("button");
var mainContent = document.getElementById("start");
var div2 = document.getElementById("div-2");

btnRed.onclick = function() {
   btn.style.animationPlayState = "running";
   btn.addEventListener("animationend", function(){
      mainContent.style.display = "none";
      div2.style.display = "flex";   
      })
    }


what is "btnRed" in your script

Apologies, it's supposed to be the button element from the var, i forgot to change the name on it.
